# Is there anything software-related I can do, to make ubuntu play high-quality mkv files smoothely?

Tags: cpu-load

I've noticed that beyond let's say..a 20 MB/s bitrate, a movie would lag, played on my laptop..

It results in me missing the highest bitrated scenes of a movie..
And sometimes having to compromise for watching the movie at a lesser quality..

I was wondering if there's anything I can do software-wise to play movies smoothley..?

At the moment Ubuntu is installed with all the default settings on an 60GB SSD

I use VLC ofcourse..

I also have 2 1TB HDD - maybe I can use them as pagefiles? I don't really know alot about this so maybe this is irrelevant..

I took the laptop battery out since it was dead..but I think this is also irrelevant..

would appriciate a response, even if there's nothing that can be done software-wise :)

Comment: @mikewhatever It's not what I meant.

I know that operating systems can be tweaked to use less resources.

I thought that maybe if I could tweak ubuntu to uer less resources, the movies would play smoothely

Comment: In that case, you should investigate, what processes use resources while you are whatching movies, ...and tell us.